# ssh-agent never forgets private keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent, ubuntu-16.04

When using `ssh` with an encrypted private key for authentication, I never have to enter the passphrase (except probably once, can't remember).

I noticed I'm running `ssh-agent` - which I don't remember setting up, is it on by default in Ubuntu 16.04? - but that should still require me to enter the passphrase at least once per session, right?

While quite convenient, this arrangement doesn't seem very secure. How can I figure out where and why the passphrase or key is being stored permanently?

Comment: Are you sure you’re running `ssh-agent` and not some other agent like a keyring program? What’s the agent connection as indicated by the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable?

Comment: It's `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`, which appears to be something else indeed. There's also an `ssh-agent` process running though.

Comment: I've opened `seahorse` (_Passwords and Keys_) but it only lists the default `id_rsa` key, not the one I'm actually using.

Comment: @DanielB this is a useless comment but I forgot to tag you :]

Comment: `ssh-add -L` will tell you what keys are stored.

Comment: @Jakuje it lists the same default key as `seahorse` does. I've checked on the server, it's not authorized there, so I'm not accidentally using that one.

Comment: Then post the verbose log of the `ssh` connection to make sure what are you using in that connection (`-vvv`).

Comment: Derp. Actually, I somehow _did_ get the wrong key authorized on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The question is invalid. The problem was that I got my default key, which doesn't have a passphrase, authorized on the server, and that one was used instead.